# Critiquing PHP-code / PerlCritic for PHP?

Tags: php, code-analysis, perl-critic

I'm looking for an equivalent of [PerlCritic](http://search.cpan.org/~elliotjs/Perl-Critic-1.105/lib/Perl/Critic.pm) for PHP. PerlCritc is a static source code analyzer that qritiques code and warns about everything from unused variables, to unsafe ways to handle data to almost anything.

Is there such a thing for PHP that could (preferably) be run outside of an IDE, so that source code analysis could be automated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I've ever heard about a PHP tool that would do all that... But a couple of existing QA-related tools, that might help you at least a bit, would be :

- **[PHPMD - PHP Mess Detector](http://phpmd.org/about.html)** -- might actually be the best choice for you, if you consider the [set of rules it checks for](http://phpmd.org/rules/index.html).
- [`PHP_CodeSniffer`](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/)
- [`PHP_Depend`](http://pdepend.org/news.html)
- Of course, [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) can help too : when generating the phpDoc, it can report errors, especially about missing doc-blocks *(doesn't report errors in the code, but can still help improve its quality !)*
- And don't forget the [Xdebug extension](http://xdebug.org/), that can generate code-coverage reports, which are especially useful when your code is unit-tested with [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/).

Those two will analyse your code, and can be run from the command-line *(i.e. outside of an IDE)*.

Answer (score 1):

See [SD PHP CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone) for a static analysis tool that finds duplicated code (exact and near misses) across large bodies of PHP code.

There are examples of a PHP clone detection run on the Joomla OSS web framework at the site.